# Error when visualize apache kylin data in apache superset

Tags: kylin, apache-superset

I tried to view apache kylin data with apache superset by an [official blog guide](http://kylin.apache.org/blog/2018/01/01/kylin-and-superset/), but I met the following error when click "visualize" button after query out result table. I have upgraded kylinpy to latest version. I know the correct sql should be "*WHERE MONTH_BEG_DT >= '1918-03-12' AND MONTH_BEG_DT <= '2018-03-12'*", but it is generated by superset auto.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12 00:00:00"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.util.DateTimeUtils.dateStringToUnixDate(DateTimeUtils.java:637)
    at Baz$6$1.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 99 more
2018-03-12 18:13:12,606 INFO  [Query eb988c1e-5f6c-4275-a9b8-1946f5976020-60] service.QueryService:328 : 
==========================[QUERY]===============================
Query Id: eb988c1e-5f6c-4275-a9b8-1946f5976020
SQL: SELECT META_CATEG_NAME AS META_CATEG_NAME,
       sum(CNT) AS sum__CNT
FROM
  (select YEAR_BEG_DT,
          MONTH_BEG_DT,
          WEEK_BEG_DT,
          META_CATEG_NAME,
          CATEG_LVL2_NAME,
          CATEG_LVL3_NAME,
          OPS_REGION,
          NAME as BUYER_COUNTRY_NAME,
          sum(PRICE) as GMV,
          sum(ACCOUNT_BUYER_LEVEL) ACCOUNT_BUYER_LEVEL,
          count(*) as CNT
   from KYLIN_SALES
   join KYLIN_CAL_DT on CAL_DT = PART_DT
   join KYLIN_CATEGORY_GROUPINGS on SITE_ID = LSTG_SITE_ID
   and KYLIN_CATEGORY_GROUPINGS.LEAF_CATEG_ID = KYLIN_SALES.LEAF_CATEG_ID
   join KYLIN_ACCOUNT on ACCOUNT_ID = BUYER_ID
   join KYLIN_COUNTRY on ACCOUNT_COUNTRY = COUNTRY
   group by YEAR_BEG_DT,
            MONTH_BEG_DT,
            WEEK_BEG_DT,
            META_CATEG_NAME,
            CATEG_LVL2_NAME,
            CATEG_LVL3_NAME,
            OPS_REGION,
            NAME) AS expr_qry
WHERE MONTH_BEG_DT >= '1918-03-12 00:00:00'
  AND MONTH_BEG_DT <= '2018-03-12 18:13:11'
GROUP BY META_CATEG_NAME
ORDER BY sum__CNT DESC
LIMIT 5000
User: ADMIN
Success: true
Duration: 1.313
Project: learn_kylin
Realization Names: [CUBE[name=kylin_sales_cube]]
Cuboid Ids: [23715]
Total scan count: 9946
Total scan bytes: 556263
Result row count: 0
Accept Partial: true
Is Partial Result: false
Hit Exception Cache: false
Storage cache used: false
Is Query Push-Down: false
Is Prepare: false
Trace URL: null
Message: null
==========================[QUERY]===============================
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check column(dimension) type in superset, make sure the type is DATA, and then please make sure kylinpy version is above 1.0.9.